# Retrieving archive messages using openfire monitoring plugin

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I use XMPP with openfire server for my website im. I've enabled monitoring service plugin, so I can archive messages.

When I send an iq stanza to retrieve a collection, the server response is an error iq stanza.

This is the request

```
<iq type='get' id='user13' xmlns='jabber:client'>
   <list xmlns='urn:xmpp:archive' with='b31315847fed0d6728d5fb763e4a53b09d6fb549@user-pc'>
     <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
        <max>
          10
        </max>
     </set>
   </list>
</iq>
```

And this is the server response :

```
<iq xmlns='jabber:client' type='error' id='user13' to='dff4bb27259100a5b158ba2477037da823d54229@user-pc/68154bb7'>
    <error code='501' type='cancel'>
        <feature-not-implemented xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
    </error>
</iq>
```

When I take a look at openfire admin console, I can view the archived conversations, so I expect my request to work fine, which is not the case.

What's going on?

Comment: I'm having the same issue and am wondering if you remember the version of the plugin you had installed.  The monitoring plugin says it's supposed to support XEP-0136 from version 1.3 onward but I'm also getting a feature-not-implemented.

Comment: @vinnybad, sorry it's been long time, I just noticed you comment. I don't remember the version exactly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your stanza is correct. But the plugin seems not working.

Openfire Monitoring plugin **isn't designed for message archiving**. The main purpose of this plugin is for traffic statistic logging & monitoring.

You can take a look on Monitoring Plugin [readme page](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/monitoring/readme.html). Message archiving has just added in version 1.3. The message are saved but it's just for logging & monitoring purpose.

I've tried this plugin too & I can't retrieve message history by this plugin.

As a solution, you can install **[OpenArchive](https://blogs.reucon.com/srt/tag/open_archive/)** plugin rather than Openfire Monitoring plugin. This plugin is specified for message archiving & retrieval.

I've install OpenArchive 1.6 & it works for me.

My reference: http://community.igniterealtime.org/message/227791#227791

Comment: Thank you so much my friend, It's been more than a month that I solved the problem... I didn't install OpenArchive, But I just used the archiving of the Monitoring service itself... I will consider using OpenArchive in a next project of course, as I delivered the previous project, +1 and Best answer :)

Best regards

Comment: I forgot totally what was my solution, sorry : But I used monitoring of other thing I think.

This is precisely the extension I used : XEP-136   http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html

Comment: @wlz How did you get OpenArchvie 1.6? None of the links to blogs work. only this github repo is there: https://github.com/srt/openarchive (and latest version is `1.0.2`)

I am worried whether I can use this plugin dependably. Are you still using it?

Comment: @vedant1811 Oops, it seems the link doesn't work anymore. I think they merge they already merge it with the Openfire Monitoring plugin (since version 1.3) http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/monitoring/readme.html

Comment: If you still want to get the Open Archive package, maybe you can try this link http://code.google.com/p/vacuum-im/downloads/detail?name=archive-1.0.6-20110831.171942-1_patched.jar&can=4&q=

Comment: Can someone confirm if OpenArchive is merged in Monitoring plugin. I'm experiencing this issue, even though I have Monitoring Plugin enabled (v 1.5.2)

Comment: @MrD i'm using Monitoring Plugin 1.7.0 with Strophe.js with this [plugin](https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugin-archive) and it works.